# paquete npm para analizar el coste computacional del código de un proyecto de Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, optimización

**Me pregunto si existe algún paquete de npm para medir el coste computacional del código de un proyecto de Node que sea similar a coverage** ¿Alguién sabe si existe algún parquete así?
. Coverage el código que ha sido cubierto por una bateria de tests. Me gustaría que existiera un paquete que te diera el coste computacional relativo del código de un proyecto. Podría hacer un análisis por las funciones haciendo una lista de mayor a menor coste computacional por función.
He buscado al respecto y lo que más se acerca es [este artículo](https://www.todojs.com/como-medir-el-rendimiento-de-un-codigo-javascript/). En el se menciona un paquete npm llamado microprofiler que mide el tiempo de ejecución de un código.

¿Para qué quiero analizar el coste computacional del código de un proyecto? Pues para saber por donde empezar a optimizarlo, que serán aquellas partes más pesadas desde un punto de vista computacional. Por ejemplo si tengo 20 funciones y una de ellas se lleva el 90% del coste computacional, pues podría empezar por la que se lleva ese 90%.

Creo que se podría desarrollar un paquete de npm basado en microprofiler para hacer el análisis de coste computacional relativo.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Alguien sabe algún paquete de npm que te haga un análisis del coste computacional relativo del código de un proyecto de Node?**

Nota: Por **análisis relativo** me refiero a que me muestre, el % de peso de cada parte del código con respecto al total del código, que podría ser por cada función.

Comment: Considera que tu pregunta puede quedar cerrada pues: **La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos**, recomiendo mejor hagas esta pregunta en el [chat]

Comment: No necesitas un paquete de npm, el propio v8 te da un profiler, y existen varias interfaces para comunicarse con el. Por si te sirve de referencia: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Comment: @BetaM: He reformulado mi pregunta. Creo que el enunciado de mi pregunta (en negrita) es muy especifico (quizás demasiado)  y no busca crear una discusión (a pesar de que haga algunas observaciones y proponga una idea)

Comment: Aún con la edición, tu pregunta sigue buscando recomendaciones de recursos externos, entonces el motivo de cierre se mantiene y mi consejo también, si aún tienes dudas recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: @BetaM: Ok, gracias.